# Postgresql Syntax error at or near " THEN "

Tags: sql, postgresql, syntax-error, create-view

I'm trying to create a view in Postgresql , but when I run this code appears this error:

> syntax error at or near " THEN "

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW VW_MONITOR_DEVICE AS
    SELECT
        P.POSIZIONE_DEVICE_ID AS MONITOR_DEVICE_ID,
        P.VALID AS VALID,
         [...]
        IF (VALID == FALSE THEN 'Valid' ELSE P.REASON_FOR_INVALID) AS DESCRIPTION,
         [...]
    FROM public.TA_POSIZIONI_DEVICE P
    JOIN ...
```

TA_POSIZIONI_DEVICE

- VALID (Boolean not null)

Comment: `case when VALID is FALSE THEN 'Valid' ELSE P.REASON_FOR_INVALID end`

Comment: @jarlh Don't forget the `END` :-)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, oops, thanks! Will edit.

Comment: There is no `IF` in SQL, where in the Postgres SQL reference did you find that?

Comment: @jarlh Thanks You! This woks :)     
case when VALID is FALSE THEN 'Valid' ELSE P.REASON_FOR_INVALID end DESCRIPTION,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [CASE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-conditional.html)

> The SQL **CASE** expression is a generic conditional expression, similar
>   to **if/else** statements in other programming languages

```
CASE WHEN condition THEN result
     [WHEN ...]
     [ELSE result]
END
```

So,

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW VW_MONITOR_DEVICE AS
    SELECT
        P.POSIZIONE_DEVICE_ID AS MONITOR_DEVICE_ID,
        P.VALID AS VALID,
         [...]
           CASE WHEN VALID = false THEN 'Valid'
                ELSE P.REASON_FOR_INVALID
           END AS DESCRIPTION,

         [...]
    FROM public.TA_POSIZIONI_DEVICE P
    JOIN ...
```

Comment: A case expression returns a value. If/else is just conditional execution of code - and has no return value (i.e. similar to a case statement.)

Answer (score 1):

you can use case

```
case when VALID = FALSE THEN 'Valid' ELSE P.REASON_FOR_INVALID end DESCRIPTION,
```

Comment: but he mention postgresql in tag

Answer (score -2):

`IF (VALID == FALSE) THEN 'Valid' ELSE P.REASON_FOR_INVALID END IF AS DESCRIPTION`

Try this ! You've got a parenthensis issue in you condition

Comment: There is no `IF` in SQL

Comment: I think he's on postgresql http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html

Comment: That link is about the _procedural_ language PL/pgSQL, it's not about the _query_ language **SQL**. Plus: the comparison operator in SQL (and PL/pgSQL) is `=`, not `==`